# Excel add sheet name to INDEX MATCH created range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel formula as follows:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($B$1, 0, MATCH(Sheet1!A3, INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0)):INDEX($J:$J, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0)), 0)), "")
```

The section I am struggling to modify is:

```
INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0)):INDEX($J:$J, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0))
```

This creates the desired range `$C$2:$J$2` when run in `Evaluate Formula`, but I am unable to add a sheet name to this reference. The desired outcome of this range will be `Sheet1!$C$2:$J$2`, however I can't seem to add this.

Is this even possible? And if so, how so?

Something along the lines of the following:

```
Sheet1! & INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0)):INDEX($J:$J, MATCH(A$14, $B$1:$B$5, 0))
```

But this is not working.

Comment: The Sheet references go inside the INDEX and MATCH not outside.  Sow you will need sheet references for every range that is inside that sheet.

Comment: Ah of course! Ok back to the drawing board thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Scott Craner the Sheet needs referencing inside the INDEX and MATCH not the outside:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1, 0, MATCH(A3, INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C, MATCH(A$2, Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5, 0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$J:$J, MATCH(A$2, Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5, 0)), 0)), "")
```